# Prove $\dfrac{1}{x} +\dfrac{1}{y} +\dfrac{1}{z} -\dfrac{1}{x+y} - \dfrac{1}{y+z} -\dfrac{1}{x+z} +\dfrac{1}{x+y+z}$ is a convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**My problem:** Prove $g(x,y,z)=\dfrac{1}{x} +\dfrac{1}{y} +\dfrac{1}{z} -\dfrac{1}{x+y} - \dfrac{1}{y+z} -\dfrac{1}{x+z} +\dfrac{1}{x+y+z}$ with $x,y,z >0$ is a convex function.
I tried to use the definition of convex function. Moreover, i tried to use the differentiating but i still get stuck with them.
Can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What would the domain be?

Comment: All of them are strictly positive variables @copper.hat

Comment: @Pipnap Actually, it is not difficult from the Hessian.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

If $f(x, y, z): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable and the Hessian is positive semidefinite in the entire domain $\Omega$, then $f(x, y, z)$ is convex.
$\Omega$ must be assumed to be convex too.
If the Hessian has a negative eigenvalue at a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0) \in\Omega$, then the function is not convex.

The domain in your case is convex, since $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$

Can you proceed?

THe Hessian Matrix reads:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{2}{x^3}+\frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+y)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+z)^3} & \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+y)^3} & \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+z)^3} \\
 \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+y)^3} & \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+y)^3}+\frac{2}{y^3}-\frac{2}{(y-z)^3} & \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}+\frac{2}{(y-z)^3} \\
 \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+z)^3} & \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}+\frac{2}{(y-z)^3} & \frac{2}{(x+y+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(x+z)^3}-\frac{2}{(y-z)^3}+\frac{2}{z^3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The domain is $x,y,z>0$ which is convex.

Comment: @copper.hat I did not read the fact that $x, y, z > 0$, sorry

Comment: @KurtGödel i used to think about using Hessian matrix. But I think, it's hard for me to compute. Because there are a lot of variables.

Comment: @Pipnap Consier that from the gradient, which is easy, you can immediately see there are no critical points. Besides that, I edited my answer showing you what the Hessian is like.

Comment: Thank you for your help